# html Heading Background color?

Tags: html, css

How can I make this number background color in heading (H3)?
I'm using Wordpress and I want to make my product heading 1/2/3/4 with the background color.

Please help me to make this.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question needs clarification. Are you asking for instructions on how to get the background colour of the number 1 (the green) and apply it to other heading tags?

Comment: you want solution with custom html and css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a example to get you started.
The main trick here is the usage of the `counters`.

- [counter-reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset)
- [counter-increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment)
- [counter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter())

  ```css
  section {
    counter-reset: test;
  }

  section h3 {
    counter-increment: test;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }

  section h3::before {
    content: counter(test) ".";
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: green;
    color: white;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <section>
    <h3>Section 1 Title 1</h3>
    
    <h3>Section 1 Title 2</h3>
    
    <h3>Section 1 Title 3</h3>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h3>Section 2 Title 1</h3>
  </section>
  ```